# How to remove unwanted `.0` s in pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

1. How to remove unwanted `.0` s when using pd.read_csv with dtype int ?

```
#sample csv data
1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0
```

2. 

```
pd.read_csv(~, dtype='int', thousands=',')
```

3. error
   unable to parse string "1,000" at position 0

in that case, I think process

1. read by str dtype or float.
2. remove unwanted ".0"
3. astype to int

but I think it is not elegant.

+)

when read by float.
it works and no error. in that case, the value is '1000.0'
but i want value is '1000' with int type

Comment: The error suggests that at least some of the values are strings with a comma delimiting thousands, so you have to read them all as strings.

Comment: I used thousands=',' together, and there is no ',' even when viewed in Excel.